# determinant of covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

how do we know if the determinant of a covariance matrix is zero, then we can write an expression between random variables such as c$_1$X$_1$ + c$_2$X$_2$ + .... + c$_n$X$_n$ = a for some real numbers c$_1$, c$_2$,...,c$_n$ and b?  Does it relate with linear dependence between column vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\det(E(\overline{X}\overline{X}^{\top}))=0 \Rightarrow \exists c\in\mathbb{R}^N\,:\,E(\overline{X}\overline{X}^{\top})c=0$, in particular,
$c^{\top}E(\overline{X}\overline{X}^{\top})c=0 \Leftrightarrow E((\overline{X}^{\top}c)^2)=0 \Rightarrow (\overline{X}^{\top}c)^2=0$, almost surely. That is, $\overline{X}^{\top}c=0$, almost surely, and your equation follows, where we defined $\overline{X}=X-E(X)$.

Comment: not quite understand it though

Comment: In words: If the determinant of the covariance matrix $E(\overline{X}\overline{X}^{\top})$ is zero, it means the matrix is not invertible, or in other words, there exists a vector $c=(c_1,\ldots,c_N)$ that lies in the kernel of the matrix. If $E(\overline{X}\overline{X}^{\top}) c=0$, so it is $c^{\top}E(\overline{X}\overline{X}^{\top})c=0$. Another relevant step is that if the expected value of a non-zero random variable is zero, then this random variable is almost surely zero. Here, $\overline{X}=[X_1-\mu\,\, X_2-\mu_2\,\, \ldots X_N-\mu_N]^{\top}$, where $\mu_i$ is the mean of $X_i$.

Comment: thanks, but how to say there is a linear combination among random variables?

Comment: The linear combination is hidden in the compact notation: $\overline{X}^{\top}c=0$ refers to $c_1 \overline{X}_1+\ldots+c_N \overline{X}_N=0$, i.e., $c_1 X_1+\ldots+c_N X_N = b$, with $b= c^{\top} E(X)= c_1 \mu_1+\ldots+c_N \mu_N$. In other words, the conclusion is that if the covariance is singular, then, you have necessarily this linear combination among the entries $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ of the random vector $X$, where the coeficients are given by a vector, in this case $c$, in the null-space of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, how can we treat the covariance matrix as the compact way you write? i.e. E[(X-E(X))(X-E(X))^T]

Comment: Yes, that is the covariance matrix $\Sigma=E(\overline{X}\overline{X}^{\top})=E[(X-E(X))(X-E(X))^{\top}]$, where $X$ is a column (random) vector, and $X^{\top}$ is the same vector but in row form. The rest is just ordinary matrix multiplication a $N\times 1$ matrix (or column-vector) times a $1 \times N$ matrix or (row vector).